# Primeira letra do menu sublinhada para atalho - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

estou tentando colocar um atalho no meu menu do meu sistema em WPF.
Em Windows form, é só alterar a propriedade text colocando o "&" antes, mas em WPF não utiliza "text" e sim "content"

Alguem me ajuda?

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80">
        <MenuItem Header="Cadastro" Height="31" Width="70" Name="ItemCadastro">
            <MenuItem Header="Empresa" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: já tentou fazer a mesma alteração que tu faria no .text, mas no .content?

Comment: Já sim, mas da erro! =/

Comment: posta o código do teu menu aqui, o xaml. Quanto mais completa tua pergunta mais fácil é para te ajudarmos

Comment: Editei la @Marciano.Andrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para colocar um atalho do teclado para um menu, o `WPF` utiliza o símbolo '_', ao contrário do `Windows Forms` que utiliza o símbolo '&' antes da letra correspondente ao atalho.

Sendo assim teu menu deve ficar assim, levando em consideração que o atalho para entrar no item Cadastro seja o C, e para o subitem Empresa seja o E:

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80">
   <MenuItem Header="_Cadastro" Height="31" Width="70" Name="ItemCadastro">
       <MenuItem Header="_Empresa" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Fonte: [Fórum da MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5ee8e360-2115-476b-b41a-d64dcc246678/how-to-add-shortcuts-commands-in-the-menuitems?forum=wpf).

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou! xD